# matplotlib plt.hline; customized the space between each horizontal lines

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm plotting horizontal lines using the following

```
K = 85
space = K
plt.hlines(y=np.arange(0,K*space,space), xmin=0, xmax=torch.randn(K))
```

It gives the plot

[image]

While; the argument `space` location the y-axis; but each line is so close with its neighbor and its very hard to put y-axis labels for each of the horizontal line

I'm more interested in increase the space (distance) between each line so that y-axis labels can be better visualized. Any help ? Thanks

Comment: The only way to get more space between lines, is to make the lines thinner, or make the figure larger. Which one would you like to persue further?

Comment: increase the height of your plot? add `plt.figure(figsize=(w,h))` before `plt.hlines`. Adjust w and h as desired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the figsize argument.

```
K = 85
space = K
plt.figure(figsize=(10,20))
plt.hlines(y=np.arange(0,K*space,space), xmin=0, xmax=torch.randn(K))
```

Comment: Thanks! somehow wasting so much time without thinking of figure size....